# Trying to set Montserrat font on all pages of my React-Native App

Tags: react-native, fonts, react-props

I'm trying to apply the Montserrat font to all elements in my react-native app but can't seem to do it.

I've downloaded all 18 of the ttf files and put them into my assets/fonts folder.

I then tried using react-native-global-props:

```
import { setCustomText } from 'react-native-global-props';

const customTextProps = {
  style: {
     fontFamily: 'Montserrat'
  }
}

setCustomText(customTextProps);
```

This didn't do anything to the text components of my app.

I then tried using defaultProps:

```
Text.defaultProps.style = { fontFamily: 'Montserrat' }
```

Also had no effect.

I also followed all the steps in this medium post about using custom fonts:

```
https://medium.com/react-native-training/react-native-custom-fonts-ccc9aacf9e5e
```

My main aim is to apply Montserrat font to every element of my entire app. I have a feeling it might have something to do with the font-type itself as Google Fonts say to apply fonts using this:

```
font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
```

However, react-native doesn't like the sans-serif as it has a hiphon so I just excluded it instead.

Any advice on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: have you got the solution on it?

Comment: Hey. I ended up changing the font to Avenir and using inline styling to make this work. Avenir didn't require the `sans-serif` part so worked normally. Sorry I took so long to reply.

```
const customFont = {
  style: {
    fontFamily: 'Avenir-Medium'
  }
}
```